How can I group dates by the first of the month, while counting values for each month?
So i have this database which is connected to a java program using H2 embedded.
In it, i have the table ASSEGNAZIONI_IN, which for this purpose contains the DATA column and the ID column, respectively of the DATE and VARCHAR(16) types.
The table looks something like this:
| DATA       | ID               |
|------------|------------------|
| 2023-03-02 | ABCDEF0123456789 |
| 2023-03-03 | DBFECA0123456799 |
| 2023-03-03 | ACFBDE0123456789 |
| 2023-03-04 | FEDCBA0123456789 |
| 2023-04-01 | FJWANN0124781248 |
| 2023-04-05 | ASFHWE1240912475 |
| 2023-05-16 | AQWRJG0124781248 |
| 2023-05-24 | AWPOAW1240912475 |
| 2023-05-16 | ASALFW0124781248 |
| 2023-10-20 | BBBBBB1231421412 |
| 2023-10-21 | CCCCCC4360282034 |

What I want is:

To get the first day of the month along with the number of distinct IDs in that month
To sort the resulting days in order of time, ascending if that matters

The output according to the table above should look like this:
2023-03-01  4
2023-04-01  2
2023-05-01  3
2023-10-01  2

I've been using this query to try to do that:
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        YEAR(ASSEGNAZIONI_IN.DATA),
        '-',
        MONTH(ASSEGNAZIONI_IN.DATA)
    ) AS MESE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ASSEGNAZIONI_IN.ID)
FROM
    ASSEGNAZIONI_IN 
GROUP BY
    MESE

But what i get is this:
2023-10     2
2023-3      4
2023-4      2
2023-5      3

The ordering is obviously broken since it sorts alphabetically on the string and I'm not satisfied of the formatting of the dates, because I would like to get the first day of the month instead of the month itself.
I also tried using the CONVERT() function but to no avail.
Any suggestion/tips are appreciated.
Edit: Thanks to @ArtBindu for the help, the final query that I used was:
SELECT 
    CAST(
        CONCAT(
            YEAR(DATA),
            '-',
            MONTH(DATA),
            '-01') AS DATE) AS FIRSTOFMONTH,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM
    ASSEGNAZIONI_IN
GROUP BY
    FIRSTOFMONTH
ORDER BY
    FIRSTOFMONTH ASC


Why did you tag this with both H2 and MySQL?

I'm new to sql and i thought they were similiar enough to justify the tag. If that's wrong/against the rules I'll edit it out.

@Xyon4 update your expected output

Yes, please remove the MySQL tag, thank you. By analogy, it's like tagging a question about Lamborghinis with a tag for Ferrari because they're both kiiiinda similar supercar marques, but I'm sure you can imagine that wouldn't go down well ;)

@Xyon4 How ID of format ABCDEF0123456789 changing to 4 digits format like 1462? What is logic behind it ? If not please correct your output data according to input or vice-versa ...

@ArtBindu The 4-digit numbers are the number of distinct IDs found for each month, not the IDs themselves

what is your output according to input table ? First submit your question proper way @Xyon4

Thank you for the suggestion. I edited the sample table and output

Thank you. Remember, when you post any question must provided as much as information to understand your issue easy and as quick as possible for others

Lets, this is my sample data:

You want to count numbers of different ids for every month. As, there is a date field, so, you have to group it by Year & Month.
Try this query it should work for you:
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT *,
  year(data_rec) as year_val,
  month(data_rec) AS month_val,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year(data_rec), month(data_rec), ID ORDER BY ID) AS row_no
  FROM T
)
SELECT 
  -- year_val,
  -- month_val,
  cast(concat(year_val, '-', month_val, '-', '01') as date) as group_by_year_month,
  COUNT(row_no) as total_distinct_ids
  FROM T1
  where row_no = 1
  GROUP BY year_val, month_val

Output:

Sample code for testing: db<>fiddle

Thank you! The query works fine and i learned something new thanks to you. Now i just need to test the efficiency of this, but it looks fine. Thanks a lot.

I slightly modified this and it works amazingly even with large amounts of data, now how would i go about writing a query that does the same but groups by first day of the week? Should i ask a separate question?

Use MySQL function: DAYNAME(data_rec), which convert date to day_name and then check according to your condition

SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, YourDateColumn), 0) 
AS FirstDayOfMonth, 
ID
FROM <TableName>;


I tried your query and I get "Data conversion error converting "INTEGER to TIMESTAMP";". Could this answer be for sql-server?

please try cast or convert() in query say query : SELECT cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, YourDateColumn), 0) ) AS FirstDayOfMonth,
ID
FROM ;
